# Bokeh: Span when plotting multiple graphs

Tags: python, graph, bokeh

I'm fairly new to Bokeh so still probably missing something with it, but I keep running into issues when trying to use Span on multiple plots if I'm generating the plots in a loop. Here's what I'm trying:

```
titleString = 'Test Plot'
plotVals = [1, 2]
upperLimit = Span(location=6, dimension='width', line_color='red', line_dash='dashed', line_width=1)
lowerLimit = Span(location=-6, dimension='width', line_color='red', line_dash='dashed', line_width=1)
xVals = [0,1,2,3,4]
yVals = [2,4,3,4,2]
for t in enumerate(plotVals):
    print(t[1])
    imgTitle = 'Span Test ' + str(t[0])
    p = figure(title=imgTitle, plot_width=800, plot_height=450, y_range=(-8, 8), x_range=(-4,8))
    p.add_layout(upperLimit)
    p.add_layout(lowerLimit)
    p.circle(xVals,yVals, size=5)            
    show(p)
    reset_output()
```

The first graph comes out as expected, but the second fails with the following message:

> ValueError: object to be added already has 'plot' attribute set

I assume I'm doing something stupid. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renderers (including annotations such as `Span`) may not be shared between multiple plots. You will need to create new spans for each plot.

If you are explicitly trying to reuse span configurations defined outside the loop, you might rewrite similar to:

```
titleString = 'Test Plot'
plotVals = [1, 2]

upper_kw = dict(location=6, dimension='width', line_color='red', line_dash='dashed', line_width=1)
lower_kw = dict(location=-6, dimension='width', line_color='red', line_dash='dashed', line_width=1)

xVals = [0,1,2,3,4]
yVals = [2,4,3,4,2]
for t in enumerate(plotVals):
    imgTitle = 'Span Test ' + str(t[0])
    p = figure(title=imgTitle, plot_width=800, plot_height=450, y_range=(-8, 8), x_range=(-4,8))

    p.add_layout(Span(**upper_kw))
    p.add_layout(Span(**lower_kw))

    p.circle(xVals, yVals, size=5)            
    show(p)
    reset_output()
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I had a feeling there was something simple I was missing that would fix it. The above solution worked perfectly.
Just to clarify on the notation; is the double asterisk in  "**upper_kw" being used because I'm passing multiple arguments (the dict declared above) to Span?

Comment: Yes, there is a good explanation of that bit of Python syntax here: https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/